# C# Parse Date/Time with a unique format I haven't seen before

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date/time with a special format I haven't seen before...

```
2011-03-08-12.26.27.000000
2011-03-08-13.00.03.000000
```

Is there an easy function in C# that I'm missing so I can convert to a date/time easily?

Thanks I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've seen this format before; it's the only format accepted natively by SQL Windows (part of Team Developer) as a datetime constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2011-03-08-12.26.27.000000", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff", null)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2011-03-08-12.26.27.000000", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thomas' answer is correct (mostly) but it won't work because of the error I mentioned as a response to his answer. Also I tried this using: "2011-03-23-13.00.00.000000" and it failed. `hh` needs to be `HH`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), code like this:

```
var dateString = "2011-03-08-12.26.27.000000";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: -1 this failed because your format was incorrect. Instead you should have: `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff`. Including the `0:` part fails but also you are missing the hyphen between `dd` and `HH`.

Comment: fixed... I removed my -1 :) I'm fair with my downvotes. I usually tell the person how they can get me to 'un-downvote'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the third `-` with , then use `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: -1 the periods will also fail. They should be replaced with colons but even then thats not going to fix his problem. The best solution is `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: I agree, you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff")`. ParseExact requires the string to be in EXACTLY the format specified, but given that restriction it can handle any data format that can be expressed as a format string, which is no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me for the pattern described for some reason. So I resorted to using the TryParseExact like so:

```
string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff";
DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dmr.DMR2ODAT, pattern, null,
             DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
    ...
```

Which worked. Posting in case someone else runs into the same issue.