# How can I parse a date like 07/21/2011 23:59:59 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I parse this date using DateTime.ParseExact?:

07/21/2011 23:59:59

in C#?

Thanks :)

Comment: How can I be negatively voted for this?

Comment: Its a very localised, "help me now" sort of question which doesnt go down well here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - more bluntly, you could have answered this yourself by reading the docs on the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) you knew was the answer (ParseExact)

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger: This question has been asked 100's of times. Your failure to search SO gets you the downvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Parse Date/Time with a unique format I haven't seen before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411322/c-sharp-parse-date-time-with-a-unique-format-i-havent-seen-before)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime.ParseExact("07/21/2011 23:59:59","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider)
```

Comment: Except the date should be 1st parameter.

Comment: @Bob Lee - well spotted. Answer updated