# How to parse and generate DateTime objects in ISO 8601 format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

There is this SOAP web service that sends me datetime objects in the following format

```
2016-03-29T12:20:35.093-05:00
```

That is day 29 of March of year 2016. Hour: 12:20:35.093 (GMT-5).

I want to be able to create a `DateTime` object, like this:

```
DateTime.Now
```

and get the string representation in the format described above and also the inverse operation, create a DateTime from a string like the one given above.

I've tried the following in order to create the date:

```
new DateTime(2016, 3, 29, 12, 20, 35, 093, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

However, I can't not see how to specifie GMT-5 there...

I don't know how to convert a DateTime to the specified string format, either.

**Using Nate's code I'm doing the following:**

```
var d = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 3, 29, 12, 20, 35, 93, TimeSpan.FromHours(-3));

FormatIso8601(d)
```

However this call is returning: "2016-03-29T15:20:35Z" instead of :

```
"2016-03-29T12:20:35.093-03:00"
```

which is what I actually need.

I think this works:

```
        d.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz")
```

Comment: Did you even attempt to try use `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: Yes, but I couldnt find the way to do it at all. Otherwise I wouldn't have come here to ask

Comment: You need to explain what you can and cannot do, exactly.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I've just added what I tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Parse Date/Time with a unique format I haven't seen before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411322/c-sharp-parse-date-time-with-a-unique-format-i-havent-seen-before)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The format you're describing is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Since you're working with timestamps that inclulde a time zone component, I'd strongly recommend using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. It makes things so much easier!

To create a `DateTimeOffset` for a given date, time, and time zone offset, use this syntax:

```
var date = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 3, 29, 12, 20, 35, 93, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));
// March 29, 2016 at 12:20:35.93 GMT-5
```

This code will format a `DateTimeOffset` as ISO 8601:

```
public static string FormatIso8601(DateTimeOffset dto)
{
    string format = dto.Offset == TimeSpan.Zero
        ? "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
        : "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz";

    return dto.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

And, to parse a string back to a `DateTimeOffset`:

```
public static DateTimeOffset ParseIso8601(string iso8601String)
{
    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
        iso8601String,
        new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK" },
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

If you must get back to a `DateTime` you can get this from the `DateTimeOffset`.[`UtcDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it safe to do this? ParseIso8601(myDate).DateTime to obtain a datetime object? In my system I would need datetimes instead of datetimeoffsets, if possible. Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but beware of unintended side effects: the time you get will depend on the local time zone of your machine. UtcDateTime will always return a UTC time, if you want to avoid that conversion.

Comment: So it's impossible to obtaina DateTime object which represents the same exact time I passed in the string to ParseIso8601?

Comment: "Exact time" in which time zone? The string may represent a different time zone than your machine is in.

Comment: Sure - UtcDateTime will be unambiguous.

Comment: If I do this: var date = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 3, 29, 12, 20, 35, 93, TimeSpan.FromHours(-5));  and then I do date.DateTime would it still be in GMT-5?

Comment: This is why `DateTime` sucks. :( It would not necessarily still be GMT-5, it would depend on the time zone of your machine. If your machine is also GMT-5, then yes.

Comment: No problem. If possible, it's highly recommended to switch everything over to `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Nate, I have a problem with the code given. Please see my edit (I'm publishing it in 5 minutes)

Answer (score 25):

A simpler way is to use the ToString method on DateTimeOffset with the "o" argument. This automatically prints the date in ISO8601 format

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o");
```

The static parse method is also capable of correctly parsing a date in ISO8601 format.

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-25-12T20:45:30.3124+01:00");
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-25-12T20:45:30.3124Z");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")`