# How to convert ISO 8601 Datetime into a specific datetime format in Java using Joda package

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am using org.joda.time.DateTime; package to convert ISO 8601 datetime for Eg "2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30" to a format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS".

Code is :

```
String dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(inputDateTimePattern);
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime("2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30");;
System.out.println("Converted datetime is: ",jodatime.toString(dtf))
```

But i get error mentioning

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: is malformed at ".T00:00:00.000+05:30"

How to convert ISO 8601 datetime format in required format in java ?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Joda-Time is replaced by the java.time classes.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30" )
```

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with its team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

In java.time, your input string can be parsed directly as a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30" );
```

A time zone is a history of offsets for a particular region. So always better to use if you are *certain* of the intended time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );  // Or "America/Montreal", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant();
```

## Joda-Time

In Joda-Time, you can parse  a string in standard ISO 8601 format with an offset-from-UTC in either of two ways:

- Constructor
  new DateTime( "2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30" ) ;
- Static `parse` method
  DateTime.parse( "2017-02-07T00:00:00.000+05:30" )

These two routes are *not* the same! See the class doc from the [`parse`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method:

> However, when this method is passed a date-time string with an offset, the offset is directly parsed and stored. As such, DateTime.parse("2010-06-30T01:20+02:00") and new DateTime("2010-06-30T01:20+02:00")) are NOT equal. The object produced via this method has a zone of DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2). The object produced via the constructor has a zone of DateTimeZone.getDefault().

Answer (score 0):

Well... the solution might be a mix between 2 already existing answers here at Stack Overflow

First - look at this post [How to parse and generate DateTime objects in ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313998/how-to-parse-and-generate-datetime-objects-in-iso-8601-format) which describes how to write such a code using C# (C# and JAVA are very similar)

Second - please use the `SimpleDateFormat` as described here [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

This combination should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got confused while using DateTimeFormat. Given time string is not in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` format. So you are getting the exception which is expected.

```
        SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        Date date=source.parse("2017-02-07T00:00:00+05:30");
        System.out.println(target.format(date));  // prints 2017-02-07 00:00:00.000
```

This code will format the date into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method

```
public static Calendar toCalendar(String iso8601string) {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(iso8601string);
    Date date = new Date(dt.getMillis());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar;
}
```