# Get date from ISO8601 format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, youtube-api

I am working with the you-tube API, which returns JSON data. The video published date is in this format:  `"publishedAt": "2017-04-30T18:18:41.000Z"`.

After deserializing the JSON object, I want to get the date from the published `DateTime` in C#.

How can I do it, and what is this format of `DateTime`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse and generate DateTime objects in ISO 8601 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313998/how-to-parse-and-generate-datetime-objects-in-iso-8601-format)

Comment: What about `DateTime.Parse("2017-04-30T18:18:41.000Z");`?

Comment: By creating a model with a DateTime property and deserializing into that model. What have you tried?

Comment: @Pikoh Yes this works for me, thank you

Comment: No, that is a bad suggestion, you shouldn't need to parse date strings manually.

Comment: @CodeCaster well yes, the best way would be as you say deserializing to the correct model. But OP asks _After deserializing the json object, I want to get date from the published datetime in C#._ So if you want to parse it after deserializing, `DateTime.Parse` should do :)

Comment: @Pikoh there's answering what the OP asks, and understanding what they're trying to do. Those are commonly different.

Comment: @CodeCaster well, you call it "understanding" but you could well call it "guessing". Maybe OP does not want to deserialize to a DateTime object, for any reason. Anyway,as I already told you, I also would go your way. That's why i didn't add it as an answer, but as a comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just need three things, video url, image and publish date, so i did't create model, I just create a class and loop through json deserialize object.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no need to manually parse a well-formatted ISO 8601 date.

Simply change the property on your model from `string` to `DateTime`:

```
public class VideoData
{
    [JsonProperty("publishedAt")]
    public DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize into that:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoData>(jsonString);
```

And Json.NET will handle the rest.