# c# Round-trip date/time pattern to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following string that I want to convert to a c# DateTime object:

```
var dateTimeString = "2020-02-25T00:00:00.000+02:00";
```

It seems I am not able to parse it with the method below:

```
var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString , "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out var startDateTime);
```

Any advices on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Check this link [String to DateTime](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: `var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out var startDateTime);`

Comment: Thanks, there was a similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313998/how-to-parse-and-generate-datetime-objects-in-iso-8601-format